# Arduino String concatenation Serial.println() doesn't work

Tags: arduino, serial-port, at-command, esp8266

I'm trying to read pass data of some text to server by first sending whole text to a function which finds its length and uses AT+CIPSEND=*length comes here* to open a TCP port later on. Everything was working fine before I add some additional info to my response data. **I'm suspecting of char limits** but couldn't find a reason even though debugging few hours.

Serial.println() doesn't show any output and string concatenation isn't healthy as it seems. The problem is that text is not being passed therefore CIPSEND doesn't work. Corresponding code section and its output shown below.

```
void sendHTTPResponse(int connectionId, String content) {
  Serial.println("SENDHTTPRESPONSE1: " + content);

  // build HTTP response
  String httpResponse;
  String httpHeader;
  // HTTP Header
  httpHeader = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
  httpHeader += "Content-Length: ";
  httpHeader += content.length();
  httpHeader += "\r\n";
  httpHeader += "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
  Serial.println("SENDHTTPRESPONSE2: " + httpHeader);
  httpResponse = httpHeader + content + " "; // There is a bug in this code: the last character of "content" is not sent, I cheated by adding this extra space
  Serial.println("HTTPRESPONSE3: " + httpResponse);
  sendCIPData(connectionId, httpResponse);
}
```

And serial monitor output. HTTPRESPONSE3 seems to be somehow empty?

```
SENDHTTPRESPONSE1: {"data":[{"id":"100"}]}{"data":[{"id":"100"}]}{"data":[{"id":"100"}]}{"data":[{"id":"100"}]}
SENDHTTPRESPONSE2: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 92
Connection: close



DATA LENGTH: 



======================================================
Executing command: AT+CIPSEND=0,0


HTTP/1.1
CoAT+CIPSEND=0,0
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Arduino is not C! And your code is not well suited such a small device. Applying desktop programming techniques to bare-metal embedded devices like Arduino is a bad idea.

Comment: What do you suggest? Or link some references please.

Comment: This is no tutoring site. But why don't you just send the text in pieces?

Comment: It's not about sending text. Just a serial.println function with string printing. I've tested printing a line with more characters and it worked just fine. What's wrong with last line I wonder. + Operator not functioning as expected.

Comment: And what do you think `Serial.println` does if not sending text? Anyway, I told you something you can try and you ignore it. That's fine for me. I'm out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer doesn't actually solve your problem.
To my excuse, I don't have the *Arduino* with me, so I can't reproduce your issue. :)

However, since you are into *"string concatenation"* style, I think you might benefit from using the source code posted here *(provided that your project has room for it)*.

It's a small *c++-style* **wrapper** around the *print* library that I wrote two years ago. It will let you write stuff like this:

```
io::cout << "This is a beautiful message!\n"
         << io::setprecision(3) << some_float << "\n"
         << io::setbase(BIN) << some_int << io::endl;
```

By default the library provides `io::cout` which prints through usual `Serial`. You can hook this library up with any object implementing the *Print interface*, e.g. *Serial* and *Software Serial*.

*The difference with what you are doing now is that by using the "<<" you'll get the same clean code-style as with "+", but you won't need to create a temporary String. Everything is immediately laid off to the output buffer to be printed out. As a result, you shouldn't incur in the same issue that you are experiencing right now. In other words, this does what @Olaf suggested in the comments, but in a fancy way. ;)*

**Note**: You probably need to fix the includes in the *test-iocout.ino* file to fit your project.

---

- *cout.h*

  ```
  #ifndef __COUT_H__
  #define __COUT_H__

  #include <Arduino.h>

  namespace io {

  /**
   * marker to end a message
   * (prints newline)
   */
  struct Endl {};
  const Endl endl = Endl();

  /**
   * marker to modify way in which numbers are
   * printed on output stream
   */
  struct setbase {
      uint8_t base;
      setbase(uint8_t v = DEC): base(v) {}
  };

  /**
   * marker to modify number of digits of doubles
   * printed on output stream
   */
  struct setprecision {
      uint8_t precision;
      setprecision(uint8_t v = 2): precision(v) {}
  };


  /**
   * class out
   *
   * Provides a C++-like interface for printing stuff on
   * an output Stream, e.g. Serial, SoftwareSerial objects
   * Assumes a separated Stream initialization handling
   */
  class out {
  public:

      out(Print& print = Serial, uint8_t fmt = DEC, uint8_t dgt = 2);
      out(const out& other);
      out& operator =(const out& other);
      virtual ~out();

      inline out& operator<<(const String& msg)
      {
          __print.print(msg);
          return *this;
      };

      inline out& operator<<(const char msg[])
      {
          __print.print(msg);
          return *this;
      };

      inline out& operator<<(char c)
      {
          __print.print(c);
          return *this;
      };

      inline out& operator<<(unsigned char uc)
      {
          __print.print(uc, __base);
          return *this;
      };

      inline out& operator<<(int n)
      {
          __print.print(n, __base);
          return *this;
      };

      inline out& operator<<(unsigned int un)
      {
          __print.print(un, __base);
          return *this;
      };

      inline out& operator<<(long l)
      {
          __print.print(l, __base);
          return *this;
      };

      inline out& operator<<(unsigned long ul)
      {
          __print.print(ul, __base);
          return *this;
      };

      inline out& operator<<(double d)
      {
          __print.print(d, __precision);
          return *this;
      };

      inline out& operator<<(const __FlashStringHelper *fsh)
      {
          __print.print(fsh);
          return *this;
      };

      inline out& operator<<(const Printable& pr)
      {
          __print.print(pr);
          return *this;
      };

      inline out& operator<<(const Endl& el)
      {
          __print.println("");
          __base = DEC;
          __precision = 2;
          return *this;
      };

      inline out& operator<<(const setbase& p)
      {
          __base = p.base;
          return *this;
      };

      inline out& operator<<(const setprecision& p)
      {
          __precision = p.precision;
          return *this;
      };

      inline int getWriteError()
      {
          return __print.getWriteError();
      };

      inline void clearWriteError()
      {
          __print.clearWriteError();
      };

  private:
      Print& __print;
      ///< output stream, must be separately initalized
      uint8_t __base;
      ///< base with which print numerical data
      uint8_t __precision;
      ///< number of fractional digits of float/double values
  };

  /**
   * Global io::cout object
   */
  extern out cout;

  } /* namespace io */

  #endif
  ```
- *cout.cpp*

  ```
  #include "cout.h"

  namespace io {

  out cout;

  out::out(Print& print, uint8_t fmt, uint8_t dgt):
      __print(print), __base(fmt),
      __precision(dgt)
  {
      // nothing to do
  };

  out::out(const out& other):
      __print(other.__print),
      __base(other.__base),
      __precision(other.__precision)
  {
      // nothing to do
  };

  out& out::operator =(const out& other)
  {
      if (this != &other) {
          __print = other.__print;
          __base = other.__base;
          __precision = other.__precision;
      }
      return *this;
  };

  out::~out()
  {
      // nothing to do
  };

  } /* namespace io */
  ```
- *test-iocout.ino*

  ```
  #include <Arduino.h>
  #include "src/cout.h"

  /******************************************************************************/
  /*** PINS & GLOBALS                                                         ***/
  /******************************************************************************/

  const uint32_t SERIAL_BAUDRATE = 4800;

  /******************************************************************************/
  /*** RESOURCES                                                              ***/
  /******************************************************************************/

  /******************************************************************************/
  /*** MAIN                                                                   ***/
  /******************************************************************************/

  /**
   * setup:
   * sets up the resources used within the arduino
   */
  void setup()
  {
      /* Initialize serial */
      Serial.begin(SERIAL_BAUDRATE);
      while (!Serial)
      {
          /* Needed by Arduino Leonardo */
      }

      /* new c++-like access to serial! */
      io::cout << "##### Arduino Station #####\n\n"
              << "- io::cout test 1.0" << io::endl;
  }

  /**
   * loop:
   *
   */
  void loop()
  {
      /* compute deltaTime */
      uint32_t curr_time = millis();
      static uint32_t start_time = curr_time; // note: initialized once!
      uint32_t deltaTime = curr_time - start_time;
      start_time = curr_time;

      io::cout << "\n> Last loop duration was: ";

      io::cout << io::setprecision(3)
              << deltaTime/1000.0f
              << " s." << io::endl;

      io::cout << "> 1025 in binary is: "
              << io::setbase(BIN)
              << 1025 << io::endl;

      delay(10000);
  }
  ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However I found a simpler solution to my problem. Whenever I use Serial.println the string inside the function fills up a portion of the memory. I've used an external library, F(), to get around of my problem.

Comment: @EnieJakiro you should post your comment as an answer, as comments might get eventually deleted. You should accept it too, if it is still possible for you. :)

Comment: Your solution worked for me as well, and it's kinda more explanatory. Cheers :)